# Creating a svg icon in DOM using JS in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, svg

**Update - Solved**

*Thanks to Robert Longson, the final code down is working very well.*

I have an def-icons.svg file under asset/image/icon folder. It holds some icons' paths that I am using in my application.

In my application, I want to create a comment asynchronously with using `create.js.erb` and the comment components include some icons.

I am using this code to create delete icon in `create.js.erb`:

```
var delete_svg_icon = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
delete_svg_icon.className = 'icon mr-3';
delete_svg_icon.role = 'presentation';

var delete_svg_icon_link = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
delete_svg_icon_link.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '<%= asset_url("icons/icons-defs.svg" + "#delete" )%>');
```

I can see the `#shadow_root` in DOM for the delete icon inside of newly added comment but it's cannot get the icon on the DOM.

My question is this; am I missing something while creating the svg? Or should I create it with all the details as `viewBox`, `fill`, `path`...

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, not 1999. You've a typo in the SVG namespace. Note that 1999 is correct for xlink.

Comment: Oh I see.. thanks for the answer. Now everything is working perfectly!